# NSTask appears to terminate early

Tags: objective-c, macos, terminate, nstask

So I'm using NSTask to run an assembler on a bitcode file using the following code:

```
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
task.launchPath = @"/usr/local/bin/llc";
task.arguments = @[bitcodePath, @"-o", asmPath];

[task launch];
[task waitUntilExit];
```

However the task doesn't seem to successfully complete, it only prints out a stub of the assembly it should generate. However if I comment out `[task waitUntilExit]`, it appears to complete successfully, generating the full assembly file. However this doesn't help as I need to perform some cleanup AFTER the task finishes. Any idea why `[task waitUntilExit]` (or any code after `[task launch]` for that matter) would be causing issues?

Comment: Is that code run in the main thread or a background thread?

Comment: It's the main thread

Comment: So that would block it, which isn't good.  Can you try running it in a background thread?

Comment: No change. Still only outputs the first part of the assembly.